# Why poor support for http cache control in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cache-control

Read book [REST practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829) and get a better understanding of web scale out base on the cache. But when I try to add http cache control in my Spring Boot project I found nothing special to the cache control. The only resource I got is [ResponseEntity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html): the javadoc. And the most useful article for ETag is http://www.baeldung.com/etags-for-rest-with-spring.

This makes me confusing... If the cache control is really great why little support for Etag generation and cache control resources found? Or maybe this is not the best practice right now?

Right now my implementation looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class Api {

    @GetMapping("/with-cache")
    public ResponseEntity cache() throws InterruptedException {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setCacheControl("max-age=3600");
        httpHeaders.setETag("\"3Rstthw\"");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Looks not very elegant. Hope some one can give an answer for this.

Comment: Does it matter "why"?  Note that the is a Q&A site, not a discussion board.

Comment: What do *you* think "better" support would be? --- Note that etags are not "generated". They represent the *version* of the resource in question. E.g. this is how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) phrases it: *An ETag is an opaque identifier assigned by a web server to a **specific version of a resource found at a URL**. If the resource representation at that URL ever changes, a new and different ETag is assigned.* Since Spring doesn't know where the payload of the response comes from, how can Spring know what version of that payload it is?

Answer (score 2):

Annotations [were considered for response headers](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9545) but decided against, so you will have to handle it manually somehow (not necessarily like in your code though).

Main reason to decide against is the way that responses are complex with possible redirections etc. so annotations are a poor fit.

Quote from the last comment

> The specific use case brought up here is Cache-Control. Note that in
>   4.1 we added ResponseEntity builders and in 4.2 we added a CacheControl builder that works with the ResponseEntity builders
>   making it very convenient to do that programmatically and has some
>   further benefits when combined with eTags and lastModified (an
>   automatic check + 304). We also specifically considered and decided
>   against a @CacheControl header since this a cross-cutting requirement.
>   Instead the WebContentInterceptor can be used to configure cache
>   settings per URL pattern and that accepts a CacheControl builder as
>   well.